# App runs in Xcode, but crashes when archived

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, avaudioplayer

I am archiving my project then using the "Export as a Mac Application" option. When I try to run the standalone version that I exported it just crashes! It seems that there's some issue with something to do with my audio, but I'm puzzled because it doesn't crash when I run it in Xcode? Any ideas? My version of Xcode is 6.4 btw. Here's the first part and last part of the crash log:

```
Process:               PianoKeyboardTest [11084]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/Music Playground.app/Contents/MacOS/PianoKeyboardTest
Identifier:            MikeFenty.PianoKeyboardTest
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           PianoKeyboardTest [11084]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-20 15:26:23.107 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        EEE0BF67-07B6-6E29-DF73-5689434AE226

Sleep/Wake UUID:       9511ADBE-72AB-468C-BB96-1A0194562CAA

Time Awake Since Boot: 23000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       14000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: fileURL != nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a05103c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff96b6c76e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a050e1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff96de28d8 _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 176
4   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff96df728a _ZN15AVAudioFileImplC2EP5NSURL19AVAudioCommonFormatbPP7NSError + 220
5   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff96df5d25 -[AVAudioFile initForReading:commonFormat:interleaved:error:] + 117
6   PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d298928 PianoKeyboardTest + 137512
7   PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d29834a PianoKeyboardTest + 136010
8   PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d298166 PianoKeyboardTest + 135526
9   PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d29800e PianoKeyboardTest + 135182
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff923d1c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff923d1b26 dispatch_once_f + 117
12  PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d297fe6 PianoKeyboardTest + 135142
13  PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d28d47b PianoKeyboardTest + 91259
14  PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d28d3aa PianoKeyboardTest + 91050
15  SpriteKit                           0x000000010d35f2b6 -[SKScene _didMoveToView:] + 76
16  SpriteKit                           0x000000010d32e8f9 -[SKView presentScene:] + 246
17  PianoKeyboardTest                   0x000000010d2941cc PianoKeyboardTest + 119244
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a00d45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89efd634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
20  Foundation                          0x00007fff887879d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbe1b9b -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 291
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbe1906 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 191
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbdea56 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 574
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbde495 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 244
25  Foundation                          0x00007fff887ba748 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290
26  Foundation                          0x00007fff887ba5b9 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
27  AE                                  0x00007fff8aae834c _Z20aeDispatchAppleEventPK6AEDescPS_jPh + 531
28  AE                                  0x00007fff8aae80c9 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 31
29  AE                                  0x00007fff8aae7fd3 aeProcessAppleEvent + 295
30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8e032c6e AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbd7eb2 _DPSNextEvent + 2249
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbd6f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fbccbf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff8fb49354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff93ae75c9 start + 1
36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff893ad286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92ff7b53 abort + 129
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff96f83a21 abort_message + 257
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff96fab9d1 default_terminate_handler() + 267
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff96b707d6 _objc_terminate() + 103
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff96fa90a1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff96fa9113 std::terminate() + 51
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff96b705ff objc_terminate + 9
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff923d1c27 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff923d1b26 dispatch_once_f + 117
10  MikeFenty.PianoKeyboardTest     0x000000010d297fe6 0x10d277000 + 135142
11  MikeFenty.PianoKeyboardTest     0x000000010d28d47b 0x10d277000 + 91259
12  MikeFenty.PianoKeyboardTest     0x000000010d28d3aa 0x10d277000 + 91050
13  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x000000010d35f2b6 -[SKScene _didMoveToView:] + 76
14  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x000000010d32e8f9 -[SKView presentScene:] + 246
15  MikeFenty.PianoKeyboardTest     0x000000010d2941cc 0x10d277000 + 119244
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a00d45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89efd634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff887879d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbe1b9b -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 291
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbe1906 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 191
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbdea56 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 574
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbde495 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 244
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff887ba748 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 290
24  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff887ba5b9 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 102
25  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8aae834c aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 531
26  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8aae80c9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 31
27  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8aae7fd3 aeProcessAppleEvent + 295
28  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e032c6e AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbd7eb2 _DPSNextEvent + 2249
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbd6f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fbccbf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fb49354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff93ae75c9 start + 1

...
```

**Edit: code causing the error**

```
-(AVAudioPCMBuffer*) loadSoundIntoBuffer:(NSString *)filename
{
    // load the collision sound into a buffer
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"mp3"]];
    NSAssert(soundFileURL, @"Error creating URL to sound file");
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioFile *soundFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:soundFileURL commonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 interleaved:NO error:&error];
    NSAssert(soundFile != nil, @"Error creating soundFile, %@", error.localizedDescription);

    AVAudioPCMBuffer *outputBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:soundFile.processingFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)soundFile.length];
    NSAssert([soundFile readIntoBuffer:outputBuffer error:&error], @"Error reading file into buffer, %@", error.localizedDescription);

    return outputBuffer;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I replaced my mp3 files with aiff files and the initial problem has changed. The app still crashes outside of Xcode, but no longer crashes on the main thread as seen below. It's something to do with the audio. Here's the code for the class handling the audio as well.

**AudioEngine.m**

```
#import "AudioEngine.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "GameData.h"

@interface AudioEngine()

@property AVAudioEngine *engine;
@property AVAudioMixerNode *mixer;
@property NSMutableDictionary *musicPlayers;
@property NSMutableDictionary *sfxPlayers;
@property NSMutableDictionary *musicBuffers;
@property NSMutableDictionary *sfxBuffers;

@property float musicVolumePercent;
@property float sfxVolumePercent;
@property float fadeVolume;
@property float timerCount;

@end

@implementation AudioEngine

int const FADE_ITERATIONS = 10;

+(instancetype) sharedData {
    static AudioEngine *sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        [sharedInstance startEngine];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(instancetype) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
        _mixer = [_engine mainMixerNode];


        _sfxPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        _sfxBuffers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        [self setVolumePercentages];
        [self initMusic];
        //[self initSfx]; //do later after music done
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) initMusic {
    _musicPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _musicBuffers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSString *audioInfoPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AudioInfo" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSDictionary *audioInfoData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:audioInfoPList];

    for (NSString *musicFileName in audioInfoData[@"music"]) {
        AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [self loadSoundIntoBuffer:musicFileName];
        [_musicBuffers setObject:buffer forKey:musicFileName];
        AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
        [_engine attachNode:player];
        [_engine connect:player to:_mixer format:buffer.format];
        [_musicPlayers setObject:player forKey:musicFileName];
    }
}

-(void) initSfx {
    _sfxPlayers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    _sfxBuffers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSString *audioInfoPList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AudioInfo" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSDictionary *audioInfoData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:audioInfoPList];

    for (NSString *sfxFileName in audioInfoData[@"sfx"]) {
        AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [self loadSoundIntoBuffer:sfxFileName];
        [_sfxBuffers setObject:buffer forKey:sfxFileName];
        AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
        [_engine attachNode:player];
        [_engine connect:player to:_mixer format:buffer.format];
        [_sfxPlayers setObject:player forKey:sfxFileName];
    }
}

-(AVAudioPCMBuffer*) loadSoundIntoBuffer:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"aif"]];
    NSAssert(soundFileURL, @"Error creating URL to sound file");
    NSError *error;
    //AVAudioFile *soundFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:soundFileURL commonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 interleaved:NO error:&error];
    AVAudioFile *soundFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:soundFileURL error:&error];
    NSAssert(soundFile != nil, @"Error creating soundFile, %@", error.localizedDescription);

    AVAudioPCMBuffer *outputBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:soundFile.processingFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)soundFile.length];
    NSAssert([soundFile readIntoBuffer:outputBuffer error:&error], @"Error reading file into buffer, %@", error.localizedDescription);

    return outputBuffer;
}

-(void)startEngine {
    [_engine startAndReturnError:nil];
}

-(void) playSfxFile:(NSString*)file {
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [_sfxPlayers objectForKey:file];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [_sfxBuffers objectForKey:file];
    [player scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferInterrupts completionHandler:nil];
    [player setVolume:_sfxVolumePercent];
    [player play];
}

-(void) playMusicFile:(NSString*)file {
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [_musicPlayers objectForKey:file];
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [_musicBuffers objectForKey:file];
    [player scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:nil];
    [player setVolume:_musicVolumePercent];
    [player play];
}

-(void) stopMusicFile:(NSString*)file {
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [_musicPlayers objectForKey:file];

    if ([player isPlaying]) {
        _timerCount = FADE_ITERATIONS;
        _fadeVolume = _musicVolumePercent;
        [self fadeOutMusicForPlayer:player];
    }

}

-(void) pauseMusic:(NSString*)file {
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [_musicPlayers objectForKey:file];
    if ([player isPlaying]) {
        [player pause];
    }
}

-(void) unpauseMusic:(NSString*)file {
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [_musicPlayers objectForKey:file];
    [player play];
}

-(void) fadeOutMusicForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayerNode*)player {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:player repeats:YES];
}

-(void) handleTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {
    AVAudioPlayerNode *player = (AVAudioPlayerNode*)timer.userInfo;
    if (_timerCount > 0) {
        _timerCount--;
        AVAudioPlayerNode *player = (AVAudioPlayerNode*)timer.userInfo;
        _fadeVolume = _musicVolumePercent * (_timerCount / FADE_ITERATIONS);
        [player setVolume:_fadeVolume];
    }
    else {
        [player stop];
        [player setVolume:_musicVolumePercent];
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

-(void) setVolumePercentages {
    NSString *musicVolumeString = [[GameData sharedGameData].settings objectForKey:@"musicVolume"];
    _musicVolumePercent = [[[musicVolumeString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                             [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                            componentsJoinedByString:@""] floatValue] / 100;
    NSString *sfxVolumeString = [[GameData sharedGameData].settings objectForKey:@"sfxVolume"];
    _sfxVolumePercent = [[[sfxVolumeString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                           [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                          componentsJoinedByString:@""] floatValue] / 100;

    //immediately sets music to new volume
    for (AVAudioPlayerNode *player in [_musicPlayers allValues]) {
        [player setVolume:_musicVolumePercent];
    }
}

@end
```

NEW CRASH LOG
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Probably one the files is missing from release target. Are you using multiple targets ? Also please attach a code that handles this file opening: [AVAudioFile initForReading]

Comment: My deployment target is OS X 10.10, so no, I only have a single target. I've attached the code to the bottom of my question.

Comment: You attached debug information, not code itself. It seems that somewhere your fileURL is nil. Show the code how you generate path for your audio files

Comment: I attached it just after I wrote the comment. I didn't think you'd check so quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the crash was that the music file I was reading in to a `AVAudioPCMBuffer` was too big. My solution was to limit the size for a buffer and use multiple buffers depending on the frame count of the audio file. The solution can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146869/avaudiopcmbuffer-for-music-files)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of your files is missing from a bundle.

Go to "Build phases -> Copy Bundle Resources" and make sure that all files are there - especially with "mp3" extension. 
Also make sure they have proper case-sensitive names.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that a couple of hours again just after you commented. I am reading the names from a plist file. As far as I can tell, all of the names match. 17 out of 17 .mp3 files are all accounted for in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section. I was reading about changing the running scheme so that it is running using the `Release` build configuration and it crashes when I run it like that. Apparently, this causes it to run in the same manner as when it's archived. The debugger just shows assembly code, which is useless to me.

Comment: One thing that I'm 100% sure about is that it is my class `AudioEngine` (which is a singleton) that manages the playback of audio files that is the problem. I just finished archiving my project again and I removed the calls to `AudioEngine` in the first scene that loads up and the app works flawlessly. Even if I limit the loading to only a couple of mp3 files it crashes so this leads me to believe that the way that I'm loading the files from disk is wrong. It works in Xcode! This is so perplexing :(

Comment: I decided to replace my mp3 files with aiff files instead. The crash occurs on a different thread from before. I think the error was the format. It is thread 13 instead of the main thread.

Comment: I think I found the problem. As per WWDC 2014 session 501, the speaker (at 54:17) reads the audio file into the buffer in chunks and makes the buffers frame capacity 128 * 1024L. As soon as I converted my code to read the file into the buffer in smaller chunks I get no more crashing, but I have a new problem of the file not playing from the beginning, but rather the beginning of the last frame of the buffer.